# Use GrapesJS with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, grapesjs

I am trying to use GrapesJS with node JS and am new to both. I have run `npm i` grapesjs and set type: module in my `package.json` file.

I run - `node myjsfile.js` in cmd prompt but the problem is that I get unknown file extension for the css file when I am just following GrapesJS getting started guide and adding the following 2 lines to myjsfile.js.

```
import 'grapesjs/dist/css/grapes.min.css';
import grapesjs from 'grapesjs';
```

If I remove the css import line of code and call node myjsfile.js then I get `document not defined` for the import grapesjs from 'grapesjs'

Is there something I am missing when importing the JS and CSS for GrapesJS in a node js file?

Tried to import GrapesJS

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't us grapesjs with node.js

Comment: Is there a different version of node I should be using then as opposed to Node JS?

Comment: This is a client-side library

Comment: so GrapesJS is a replacement for Node.js?

Comment: From what I've read on their website, it's a different tool used for different things. I think that you should explain why do you want to use it with node.js

Comment: We want to use GrapesJS as part of an application that will be powered from an node.js server on the backend.

Comment: Grapes is frontend tooling. It's built in Node, but doesn't run _in_ Node. It depends on having a Document, CSS engine, etc. You need all sorts of setup to get it working if you're doing if from scratch, but [their CLI](https://github.com/artf/grapesjs-cli) should make it easy.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'm able to get grapesjs working when init() is in an html file I'm still confused how to go about initialising the grapes object in what they call modern javascript in the getting started section of their website as opposed to html. Any guidance on how to utialise grapes in modern javascript would be greatly apppreciated.